# Cross table into normal table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am getting the data from the `Excel` sheet on monthly , need to import data into the `Access` table as same as excel sheet. Then I need to transform the Access table (Input table) into the Normal Access table( Output table)...

Kindly provide suggestions

1. how to create a dynamic input table in the access ..since new column can add or remove in the excel sheet (ex :201211)
2. How to convert input table into Output table in the access.

**Input Table : ( Column name :  Product | Location | 201209 | 201210 )**

```
Product | Location | 201209 | 201210 

X       | DK       | 10     | 12
y       | DK       | 10     | 12
```

**Output table :**

```
Product | Location | Date  | Quantity 

X       | DK       |201209 | 10
X       | DK       |201209 | 12
Y       | DK       |201210 | 10
Y       | DK       |201210 | 12
```

My input table contains more columns ( ex : 201208 , 201209, 201210 ....... 201402)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get your desired output from a query like this:

```
Select Product, Location, '201209' as [Date], Table.[201209] as Quantity from Table
UNION
Select Product, Location, '201210' as [Date], Table.[201210] as Quantity from Table
```

You mentioned that your column names could change. You could get around this by creating a VBA subroutine which would look at the TableDef, and construct a SQL query for all the columns which would then insert records into a table.

Comment: +1 Also consider `UNION ALL` could be faster.  Just `UNION` is useful to avoid duplicate rows, but I doubt that applies here.

Comment: @HansUp Yes, UNION ALL would be faster, but if it's a small table or run infrequently it might not make a huge difference. If the query was going to be used for an INSERT command into a table, you might have to change the column headers as "Date" is a reserved word in Access and should be avoided.

Comment: Default to `UNION ALL`. Only choose just `UNION` when you want to weed out duplicate rows.  Don't waste time on the mental calculation "this case is a smallish number of rows, so a performance benefit from UNION ALL is unlikely to be noticed".  `UNION ALL` will only ever be the wrong choice when it returns duplicate rows you don't want.

Comment: Thanks KFleschner , I will be using for the "VBA subroutine which would look at the TableDef, and construct a SQL query for all the columns " as you suggested.. For Transforming Data from cross table into the normal table ..thinking it has more colums in the table.. Thanks for your help :)